# Pass data from one database to another via xml

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xml, phpmyadmin

I have two mysql databases(phpmyadmin)  "db_One" and "db_Two" on the same server.Both databases have common table named 'customer'.
Customer table contains columns ,customer_id and customer_name.
I need to update db_One from db_two every 30 minuets.How can I do that using xml or any other ways to do that? since I am new to xml I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: The last thing you want to do is using xml in such case. Simply have a query via pho and parse it in a loop to insert whatever into the second one

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you use a stored procedure, that way yo can execute the "update" every 30 min, or what you define, take a look here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

for example, First create the procedure

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE update_db
   BEGIN
   insert into db_two select *  from db_one
   END
```

after that just create a event to call the procedure, for example

```
       CREATE EVENT update_db
       ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1800 SECOND
       DO
       CALL update_db();
```